# Location of a program identifier

Tags: permissions

Where do I find the program [identifier] to fix the microphone and camera permissions in Terminal for apps like Messenger, Zoom, Teams, etc. that's running MacOS Ventura on an unsupported MacBook Pro 2013 using Opencore?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/459474/macos-ventura-13-3-apps-dont-show-in-camera-and-microphone-privacy-security-s